AgGrid Row Moves to top after data refetch,How to avoid this
We used Ag grid community for a tabel creation but once updated in a cell, go to the top in the grid....
We are doing a POC whether properly work with ag grid enterprise... but still we didnt get a answer..
Once updated a cell it should be stay at that place not should go to top...
tried all below but nothing works.... anyone here to guide on this?
nothing below works
 <AgGridReact ref={gridApiRef} // suppressMovableColumns={true} rowData={rowData} columnDefs={colDefs} onGridReady={onGridReady} suppressScrollOnNewData={true} // animateRows={false} // resetRowDataOnUpdate={true} // enableCellChangeFlash={false} // immutableData={true} // domLayout="autoHeight" // deltaSort={true} />
ensureIndexVisible(index, 'middle');
We are using custom cell component, dynmaic headers, and 1st columns having students and rest of the coulmns having their schedules....
dynamic headers contains the date ...
I have used suppressScrollOnNewData , ensureIndexVisible also didnt work...
Still go to the top of the Row after update in the data... Any solution for this?
I have tried many nothing works... any ideas guys
